# select the class of td

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select the class of the td that is clicked inside my table and then pass it to a function.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class = "Vespalx">Vespa lx</td>
    </tr>
</table
```

So in jQuery I tried to select it whit:

```
$type = $(this).closest("table").find("div");
```

then I want to perform an action on $type:

```
$type.click(function(){
   $("body").hide();
}):
```

But now nothing happens!
Did I make a fault with selecting the div?

Comment: You should provide more code to clarify what's `$(this)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this helping ?

```
$('td').click(function(){
  $(this).attr('class');
  // or
  $this.classList;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for a div. There isn't any div in your sample code. 
I adapted your piece of javascript to find the td.

`$type = $(this).closest("table").find("td");`

alternatively you could use the css class selector (Vespalx) also.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clarify what is `$(this)` in your code. However this is a solution:

```
$type = $("body").find("table").find("td");
$type.click(function(){
    $("body").hide();
});
```

I replaced `$(this)` with `$("body")` and I used find method to get the table instead of closest that doesn't work for me. Then I fix the error of second find. In your second find you search for a div and not for a td. At the end of your code I see : and this is wrong. You must use ; and not :

Answer (score 0):

Tnx for all the answers!!!
Know I see that my question was a vague.
But what I wanted was select the class of the td that is clicked and then do something with this class.

See my code:

```
function scooter (klas) {
                    var clas = $(klas);
                    clas.addClass("allscootervis");
                    //$(".allscooter").css("display", "block");
                    //$scooter = $("div > this", ".ScooterContent");
                    $(".introduction").replaceWith("");
                }
$("td").click(function(){
                    $typeun = $(this).attr('class');
                    //$type = '$(".' + $typeun + '")';
                    $type = '.' + $typeun;
                    scooter($type);
                });
```